# I need to get the source of my net application which is obfuscated

Tags: hardware

I need to recover the source of my net application which is obfuscated.
I formatted the PC by error and lost the information.  And some ransomware obfuscated my files,

Is it possible to recover my source code if the app is obfuscated?

I need to get this service to recover the source I need.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't I believe in this?...

deobfuscate the file first.

Then, use this:

[reflector](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector) and

[reflexil](http://reflexil.net/), [active fork](https://github.com/sailro/Reflexil)

Comment: And don't miss dnSpy!